# Duplicate API requests before state has time to update global state

Tags: reactjs, redux

** Note: This is such a common use-case that I'm sure it has been asked and answered, but I am not finding it. Apologies if it has been resolved elsewhere**

I am trying to create a component that makes a simple API request, but only if another component didn't already initiate such a request.

For tracking whether a request is currently in progress I have a global state variable:
`isFetching = false`.

Here's my component with the basic logic to achieve that:

```js
function ComponentChild = () => {

  // A selector that gets the fetch state from the global store
  const isGloballyFetching = useSelector((state) => selectIsFetching(state));

  // A selector that gets the fetched data from the global store if it is already available
  const fetchedData = useSelector((state) => selectFetchedData(state));
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  /** a side-effect that makes a request for the data,
  but only if:
  1) it hasn't been fetched yet and
  2) there is no other request in progress
  */
  useEffect(() => {
    // If data is already fetched or if there is a request in progress, do nothing
    if(fetchedData || isGloballyFetching) return;
    
    // Making the request
    // 1. Update the global state to indicate that a request is in progress
    // 2. Make the request
    // 3. Update the global state to indicate that the request is complete
    dispatch('REQUEST_START');
    //.... Logic that makes the request...
    someRequest().then(()=>{
           dispatch('REQUEST_END');
    })


  },[]) // Run once on mount
}
```

And here's the parent component rendering 100 instances of the child component:

```js
function ComponentParent = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        {/* Render the child component 100 times */}
        {Array.from(Array(100).keys()).map((i) => (
            <ComponentChild key={i} />
        ))}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Now, the behavior I was hoping to get is that the first child component will see that no requests are in progress, set `isFetching` to `true` and be the only component that makes a request because:

1. Following components should see that the state is set to `isFetching` and not initiate a new request, or
2. the initial request will end, and therefore `fetchedData` will be populated which will also prevent a redundant request.

However, what is happening is that I am getting 100 api calls, because the global state gets updated slower than the parent and child components take to render. So only AFTER all 100 child components made their request, `isFetching` gets updated to `true`.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: You can fetch the data in `ComponentParent`, and then pass that data as props to your child components.

Comment: It's a text book case for thunks (async action creators) which have access to a `getState()` function, which allows you to get an immediate, up-to-date look at the state so you can skip triggering the API call.

Comment: Doubling down on @timotgl's comment, using Redux-Toolkit Query even goes a step further and handles query/mutation caching (only fetches when it needs to) and provides hooks to the UI to know when data is being loaded/fetched.

Comment: I'm using sagas, which I thought act similarly to thunks in terms of how the state gets updated. Is that not the case?

Comment: @SarangaB, that won't work for me. For a number of reasons I need the fetch to be in the child component.

Comment: Ended up using redux RTK to de-dup the requests